# Prometheus Smoothing Utilization Metric

Tags: prometheus

Trying to figure out how to smooth this metrics over 5m so data is not so jumpy. Current metric shows the worker utilization by taking worker used divided by number of workers. 
http_Stats_Resque_worker_main_working{app_name='workflow'}/http_Stats_Resque_worker_main_total{app_name='workflow'}

[image]

Comment: Metric is reported every 30 seconds but I want the autoscaler to get a reading/query not of the last 30 seconds but metric smoothed over a given interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) and [irate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#irate).

Read also robustperception blog [post](https://www.robustperception.io/what-range-should-i-use-with-rate)